# Removed Windows7 in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: windows-7

After removing Windows7 using GParted Partition Editor, I wonder if there is any files left that will affects Ubuntu 12.04. Is there any command in the terminal to clean all the remaining files from Windows7?
[image]

Comment: You removed [formatted] the entire Windows partition , so don't worry nothing is left. Seems like you are worried about viruses ?. Was your windows in 2 GB drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be no files recoverable from your old Windows installation without using forensic software tools.

If you *really* want to bleach a drive clean, boot a LiveCD, open a terminal.

List the available disk and partitions (to work out which device your disk is)

`sudo fdisk -l`

And then copy zeroes over the whole surface

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=8M`

**Replace** the `/dev/sda` with the disk device that you wish to wipe (`/dev/sda` being the first available hard drive in most modern systems). Be *very careful*. If you have external backup drives, etc, I recommend you unplug them before doing this

Argument reference

- `dd` ; a raw file copy / convert tool
- `if` input file, in this case, a virtual device full of infinite zeroes
- `of` output file, your disk device (in Unix, everything is a file)
- `bs` block size ; we use 8M to make things go faster

Comment: If you worried about forensic tools, even this will be insufficient. You'd have to write random strings repeatedly; there are tools available to do that.

Comment: While scientific studies with sensitive equipment have recovered data from drives that have been zero-wiped, it's sufficient to defeat software forensics, and most commercial data recovery labs would be hard pressed to recover anything. There is some argument that the findings mentioned above are no longer true of more modern hard drives with much smaller, more fragile, magnetic domains. So all in all, unless you have the NSA chasing you, a simple zero-wipe is probably enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you have completely reformatted your drive to EXT4, then I don't think there will be any old Windows file left that should bother your Ubuntu installation.

However I'm not sure about those 1.98 GB partitions. If there is nothing on them that you need, I think it should be safe to delete them and use the space as linux swap instead.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried to delete the unknown /dev/sda5, but when I open again the GParted, its still there., I have no idea what it is.